# PHP functions that has direct output to browser

Tags: php

Some functions in PHP (for ex. phpinfo, var_dump, print_r) has a direct output to browser and to store its result to a variable we need to use ob_* functions.

I cited the example of three these functions. Do you know any more? Is there a list of these functions? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look `var_export` too

Comment: `echo` is such a function :-)

Comment: `echo` isn't a function it is a language construct.

Comment: @Anton The final answer will also depend on the set of extensions you've installed

Comment: @hek2mgl http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php its also rendered as a function.

Comment: @dognose Have you read that page? Just the first paragraph? ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl yes. It's a function that can be used without `()` which makes it a language construct.

Comment: I told you should read the (complete) first paragraph. If you don't believe me, try: `php -r "var_dump(function_exists('echo'));" ` .. And, is it a function? :)

Comment: @hek2mgl nice inch-pinching there. This however would apply for `print, unset, isset, empty, include, require, die, ...`

Comment: @dognose Yes, that's true. Just to name one side-effect, you can't use them as callbacks. If you wish so, you need to wrap them in a closure (or function)

Comment: I posted a similar question with an fair list, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310866/1695680

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I know that PHP's [`printf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function will also echo it's output instead of returning data. But to my knowledge, there's no list out there of all PHP functions that echo information rather than returning it.

A bit of a sidenote though, `print_r` actually has a boolean optional second parameter that allows you to control whether or not it echos it's output, or returns it.

Comment: and obviously `phpinfo()`, `imagepng()`, `imagejpg()` and so much more :)